# How to add column in table grouped by value and max value in date column using sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I have a table:

```
id   date           val
1    10.08.2022     10
1    12.08.2022     11
1    08.08.2022     15
1    16.08.2022     9
2    02.07.2022     2
2    01.07.2022     4
2    30.07.2022     7
```

I want to create two new columns last_v and max_v which are equal to last val for each id by date and maximum val per id. So desired output is:

```
id   date           val   last_v   max_v
1    10.08.2022     10      9        15
1    12.08.2022     11      9        15
1    08.08.2022     15      9        15
1    16.08.2022     9       9        15
2    02.07.2022     2       2        7
2    01.07.2022     4       2        7
2    30.06.2022     7       2        7
```

How could I do that?

Comment: Join the table with a subquery that gets the last and max value for each group.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql?rq=1 for how to get the last value in each group.

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.x you can also do it in a single query using window functions.

Comment: @Barmar i don't really understand how to do that

Comment: @Barmar i just started to work with window functions. i don't see how to use it here((

Comment: What is keeping the order in your table?

Comment: @PM77-1 I think it's the date, which is in DD.MM.YYYY format, but `30.07.2022` is a typo for `30.07.2022`.

Comment: @Bamar - I see `10, 12, 08, 16` for `08` month.

Comment: Ugh, I also typoed it. I meant it's a typo for `30.06.2022`, which is in the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions!

```
select t.*,
    first_value(val) over(partition by id order by dt desc) last_val,
    max(val) over(partition by id) max_val
from mytable t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CFszfAxQ)**:

| id | dt | val | last_val | max_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-08-08 | 15 | 9 | 15 |
| 1 | 2022-08-10 | 10 | 9 | 15 |
| 1 | 2022-08-12 | 11 | 9 | 15 |
| 1 | 2022-08-16 | 9 | 9 | 15 |
| 2 | 2022-06-30 | 7 | 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 2022-07-01 | 4 | 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 2022-07-02 | 2 | 2 | 7 |